# How to implement UICollectionsVIEW in TAbleViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, collections, uicollectionview

I need to implement UICollections in my tableViewCell. I want use Collection in place of my ImageView if array of my custom class contains some images (if not - I use simple cell).

So, How can I add collection presentation in my cell?

```
         if (!([oneNews.images count] > 0))
    {
    cell.cellTextLabel.text = oneNews.text;
    cell.cellTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    if ([oneNews.image length] > 0)
    {
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:oneNews.image]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        cell.cellImageView.image = image;
    }
    cell.cellLikeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", oneNews.likesCount];
    cell.cellRepostLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", oneNews.repostsCount];
    cell.cellCommentsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", oneNews.commentsCount];
    cell.cellDateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", oneNews.pubDate];
    } else {
        //collection
    }
```

Comment: On iOS there is nothing like UICollections? Do you mean UICollectionView?

Comment: I find answer here , its works for me very well http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell